# Missing assembly/component/dll puzzle

Tags: sql-server

I'm (still!) rebuilding a Team System Win 7 build server. I've install the full Sql Server 2005 Express with SDK and all the bells and whistles, and rebooted the server.

However when I launch a build the compile step fails with the following message: "The type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer'"

This code all compiles on our development machines, so the code must have the correct references and it looks like something is not installed on the build server - but what?

(We are using Sql Srvr 2005 for specific reasons)

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation for TFS [2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd631889.aspx) and [2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd631889%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), SQL 2008 or later is required.

(I think the specific error message you're getting is because some methods were moved into different assemblies between SQL 2005 and 2008)

Comment: The puzzle is that we're successfuly compiling this code on Win 7 machines using VS2008 Team System and Sql Server 2005 Express installed. It is only on the new build server ( the old XP build server is fine) that we get this error. It's a question of what needs to be installed to get the sql server 2005 SMO stuff installed, I think

Comment: @haughtonomous - you can get the SQL 2005 SMO installer from MSDN: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15748 (search the page for SMO) - or have you tried that already?